# Changing cursor in an AS3 game using buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make my game change the cursor when pressing a button. However after pressing one of the buttons, I'm unable to change it again (seems like the cursor gets in the way). I thought setting `mouseCursor.mouseEnabled = false;`

would fix it, but it seems like it didn't. 
Here's my code, could someone tell me what am I doing wrong please?

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.ui.*;

import Game.*;

public class GameController extends MovieClip
{
    private var mouseCursor:MovieClip;

    public function GameController()
    {

    }

    private function followMouse(evt:Event)
    {
        mouseCursor.x = mouseX;
        mouseCursor.y = mouseY;
    }

    public function startGame()
    {   
        needleOn = false;

        mcGameUI.btnMixBlue.addEventListener(
                MouseEvent.CLICK, mixBlue);

        mcGameUI.btnMixRed.addEventListener(
                MouseEvent.CLICK, mixRed);

        mcGameUI.btnMixYellow.addEventListener(
                MouseEvent.CLICK, mixYellow);

        mcGameUI.btnNeedle.addEventListener(
                MouseEvent.CLICK, activateNeedle);


        mcGameUI.mouseEnabled = false;
    }       

    private function mixBlue(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        if (mouseCursor != null)
        {
            removeChild(mouseCursor);
            mouseCursor.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followMouse);         
            mouseCursor = null;
        }
            mouseCursor = new BlueBubble(mouseX,mouseY);
            mouseCursor.gotoAndPlay("idle");
            mouseCursor.mouseEnabled = false;
            mouseCursor.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followMouse);            
            addChild(mouseCursor);
    }
    private function mixRed(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        if (mouseCursor != null)
        {
            removeChild(mouseCursor);
            mouseCursor.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followMouse);         
            mouseCursor = null;
        }
            mouseCursor = new RedBubble(mouseX,mouseY);
            mouseCursor.gotoAndPlay("idle");
            mouseCursor.mouseEnabled = false;
            mouseCursor.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followMouse);            
            addChild(mouseCursor);
    }
    private function mixYellow(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        if (mouseCursor != null)
        {
            removeChild(mouseCursor);
            mouseCursor.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followMouse);         
            mouseCursor = null;
        }
            mouseCursor = new YellowBubble(mouseX,mouseY);
            mouseCursor.gotoAndPlay("idle");
            mouseCursor.mouseEnabled = false;
            mouseCursor.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followMouse);            
            addChild(mouseCursor);
    }

    private function activateNeedle(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        if (mouseCursor != null)
        {
            removeChild(mouseCursor);
            mouseCursor = null;
            mouseCursor.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followMouse);         
        }
        mouseCursor = new Needle();
        mouseCursor.mouseEnabled = false;
        addChild(mouseCursor);
        mouseCursor.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followMouse);            

    }


}   
}
```

Comment: it is because cursor clip is mouse enabled which means that it captures any mouse clicks, I think mouseEnabled is not enough. Can you show your mouseCursor related code (e.g. class for mouseCursor)?

Comment: Here's the code for the classes, they're all essentially the same
http://pastebin.com/6j62x7nM

Comment: that says nothing:) set `mouseCursor.mouseChildren=false;` and test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set:

```
mouseCursor.mouseEnabled = false;
mouseCursor.mouseChildren = false;
```

mouseEnabled turns off only the container `mouseCursor` but inside this clip you still can have mouseEnabled elements thus `mouseChildren` should be also turned off.

mouseChildren is defined in DisplayObjectContainer which means that cursors made out of shape or bitmap will not have this property, so you need to test if it exist first.

```
if(mouseCursor is DisplayObjectContainer){
{
    mouseCursor.mouseChildren = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this fixed the problem partially, but now when I go from one of the first three cursors to the 4th one `Needle()` it crashes...
edit: the Needle() class is a default one (the one made by the constructor)

Comment: ten add crashlog so we can see where it is broken:) maybe your cursor is not a container thus mouseChildren doesnt exist on it.

Comment: `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at GameController/activateNeedle()`

Comment: additional info:
when I comment out this part `            mouseCursor.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followMouse);         
`
on activateNeedle() it stops crashing... no idea why though

Comment: look what are you doing, you set mouseCursor to null and then trying to access it.